# Discard points with X,Y coordinate close to eachother in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (it is actually several hundred MB long):

```
    X   Y   Size
0   10  20  5
1   11  21  2
2   9   35  1
3   8   7   7
4   9   19  2
```

I want discard any `X, Y` point that has an euclidean distance from any other X, Y point in the dataframe of less than `delta=3`. In those cases I want to keep only the row with the bigger size.

In this example the intended result would be:

```
    X   Y   Size
0   10  20  5
2   9   35  1
3   8   7   7
```

Comment: This is a really hard problem. Plus, if you data has an additional row `11 20 8`, would you keep `9 19 2`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @QuangHoang You are right, those cases make the problem particularly hard. But I would keep the biggest source within those `delta=3` interval (even if it implied discarding two smaller sources `delta=6` appart in the worst of cases).

Comment: @G.Anderson Duplicating the table and then comparing all points between the duplicated ones with `sklearn.neighbors BallTree` in search of matches. I think this is where to start, but I don't want to be creating `n=rows` new tables to solve the problem.

Comment: I would ask that you edit your question with the code you've tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt. It's helpful to have a full [mcve] for others to provide assistance

Comment: you need graph theory for this, and the core issue of the question is not related to coding. But since it's a cool question, people will help :)

Comment: What's the dimension of your grid relative to delta=3? in other words, what are x,y max?

Comment: @run-out In the example: `Xmin=16381.413, Ymin=20382.482, Xmax=19846.546, Ymax=20345.651`. In the final product: `Xmin>=0, Ymin>=0, Xmax<30000, Ymax<30000`

Comment: What is the sequencing algorithm for point removal?  Consider a 1D case of (0, 0, 10), (0, 2, 9), (0, 4, 8).  Point (0,4) might be removed because it's within 3 units of the larger (0, 2) ... however, (0, 2) can be removed for being within 3 units of the larger (0, 0).

Comment: Also, please determine what response you want.  You've tagged two languages, but this appears to be an algorithm question.  If you're looking for an implementation, then you need to describe your algorithm and show your coding attempt.  If you want help with the algorithm, show what you've considered, and delete the languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is stated, the behavior of the desired algorithm is not clear about how to deal with the chaining of distances.

If chaining is allowed, one solution is to cluster the dataset using a density-based clustering algorithm such as [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html).

You just need to set the neighboorhood radius `eps`to delta and the `min_sample` parameter to 1 to allow isolated points as clusters. Then, you can find in each group which point has the maximum size.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
X = df[['X', 'Y']]
db = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=1).fit(X)
df['grp'] = db.labels_
df_new = df.loc[df.groupby('grp').idxmax()['Size']]
print(df_new)

>>>
    X   Y  Size  grp
0  10  20     5    0
2   9  35     1    1
3   8   7     7    2
```

Comment: You are right the original questions didn't state this, although it was clarified in one of the comments. Thank you, this works accordingly and was accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below script and also try improving it.

```
#get all euclidean distances using sklearn; 
#it will create an array of euc distances; 
#then get index from df whose euclidean distance is less than 3
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
Z = df[['X', 'Y']]
euc = euclidean_distances(Z, Z)
idx = [(i, j) for i in range(len(euc)-1) for j in range(i+1, len(euc)) if euc[i, j] < 3]

# collect all index of df that has euc dist < 3 and get the max value
# then collect all index in df NOT in euc and add the row with max size
# create a new called df_new by combining the rest in df and row with max size
from itertools import chain
df_idx  = list(set(chain(*idx)))
df2 = df.iloc[df_idx]
idx_max = df2[df2['Size'] == df2['Size'].max()].index.tolist()
df_new = pd.concat([df.iloc[~df.index.isin(df_idx)], df2.iloc[idx_max]])  
df_new
```

Result:

```
    X   Y  Size
2   9   35  1
3   8    7  7
0   10  20  5
```