# Pandas: Best way to return all data points near any member of a list of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a few thousand rows. Among the features/columns are x and y coordinates (which are two separate columns). I need to return all of the rows that are within a certain radius of a separate list of coordinates.

I can do this by iterating over every row, but is there a faster way to do this?

Also, I can change the list of coordinates to be in any format, but for simplicity's sake, we can say it is like this:

```
[(x1, y1), (x2, y2) ...]
```

Comment: I never needed it but it looks like job for some GIS system. I found [GIS in Python](http://www.data-analysis-in-python.org/t_gis.html)

Comment: Try looking at the answers here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872262/10888655

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy if you would like to do

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
import numpy
b=numpy.array([(1,3),(2.5,3)])
c=numpy.array((3,3))
print(norm(b-c,axis=-1))
```

result will be `[2.  0.5]`
Simply b is your big array casted with numpy
c is the coordinate you want to test.

Comment: Ok so this returns the distances from one test point. I need to be able to do it from multiple test points and with a pandas dataframe. Also, there are more columns in the dataframe than just the x and y coordinates.